# Import image from json source (create-react-app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have some json with data and one of param is path to my local folder with images:

```
// data.json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
     "image": "assets/somepic.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
     "image": "assets/anotherpic.png"
  }
  // similar data goes there
]
```

Then I import those data into my component

```
import data from "data.json"
```

and I want to map thru this data:

```
render() {
  return (
     data.map((item) => (
       // Ofc it won't work if I just put {item.image} in src,
       // because we need to import image before use it
       // that's why I'm trying to use require
       <img src={require(item.image)} />
     ))
  )
}
```

But it won't work.
How can I use images, which local patch is specified in json data for create-react-app?

Please, note: app should NOT be ejected.

Comment: Instead of map, try forEach

Comment: No, it doesn't work

Comment: You also need to wrap the img tags within a div tag.

Comment: And why I need that?

Answer (score 0):

Check if `create-react-app` has Webpack configured to bundle images (.png check `webpack.config.js`) out of the box. If so, it seems like you're only missing a relative path starting like this './assets/anotherpic.png' if `assets` is in the same folder as the component.

Comment: create-react-app has webpack files only for ejected apps.

Comment: `assets/anotherpic.png` is not a relative path by Webpacks definition. it may be looking for the file in your modules. https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/#relative-paths

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that load from require right paths. Your photos doesn't located `assets/anotherpic.png` , maybe you should load from absolute path `./assets/anotherpic.png`

Answer (score 0):

If you use Webpack v4, have you try to use `require.context()`?

> It allows you to pass in a directory to search, a flag indicating whether subdirectories should be searched too, and a regular expression to match files against.

[See the source into the webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext)

Your code can be something like that :

data.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
     "image": "somepic.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
     "image": "anotherpic.png"
  }
  // similar data goes there
]
```

file.js

```
const pathToAssets = require.context('assets/');

...

render() {
  return (
     data.map((item) => (
       <img src={pathToAssets(item.image)} />
     ))
  )
}
```